# How to pass 'env' var to a Python script via an arg in subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing an Python wrapper where a Python script creates a custom env variable by adding a large number of elements.

For example:

```
env['DEBUG'] = '1'
env['TBB_NUM_THREADS'] = str(args.threads)
...
```

This first wrapper calls a second wrapper via `subprocess.Popen` like this:

```
command = ['wrapper2.py'] + args
subprocess.Popen(command, env=env).wait()
```

I need the second wrapper to have the same env as the first.
Ideally, I would like to modify the above assignment so the second argument is the env. In this way the second script can easily access it and set its env to that of the first script.

```
command = ['wrapper2.py'] + env + args
```

But this causes the following error: "Typeerror: can only concatenate list (not "instance") to list"

What would be the best way to approach this problem?
Note: I am using Python 2.7

Comment: If you want to pass around just one thing that sets both `args` and `env`, then `kwargs` is your friend. That is: `kwargs = { "args": ['wrapper2.py'] + args, "env": env }` then invoked as with `subprocess.Popen(**kwargs)`

Answer (score 1):

It's an ugly hack, but if you're unwilling to pass `env` out-of-band from `args` as a separate argument, you can use the `env` UNIX utility to set your environment variables instead of using the `subprocess` `env` facility.

That is:

```
args = [ 'env', 'DEBUG=1', 'TBB_NUM_THREADS=%s' % (arg_threads),
         './wrapper2.py' ] + wrapper2_args
```

---

A less-ugly hack is to pass around a single kwargs list that contains both:

```
kwargs = {
  'args': [ './wrapper2.py' ] + wrapper2_args,
  'env':  { "DEBUG": "1", "TBB_NUM_THREADS": str(arg_threads), }
}
```

...and then pass it in using `**kwargs` syntax:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(**kwargs)
```

Comment: I was thinking of that as a last resort, but I have a large number of env additions. Hence my question for a more elegant way.  I am gong to try what you wrote earlier regarding kwargs

Comment: If you want *elegant*, do the right thing and keep `args` and `env` out-of-band from each other. Trying to mush them into a single list is an ugly, awful hack in the first place.